# html5 + javascript playing wave sound

Tags: javascript, html, audio, wav, html5-audio

I'm having a wave file that is 5 secs long.
How can I implement a playback feature that can play from a point in timeline until another.
for example, play from 3.00s - 4.00s (only a segment of original waveform)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not tested, but you can check this: [MDN: Using HTML5 audio and video # Specifying play back range](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_HTML5_audio_and_video?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Using_audio_and_video_in_Firefox#Specifying_playback_range)

> A few examples:
>
> http://foo.com/video.ogg#t=10,20
>
> Specifies that the video should play the range 10 seconds through 20 seconds.
>
> http://foo.com/video.ogg#t=,10.5
>
> Specifies that the video should play from the beginning through 10.5 seconds.
>
> http://foo.com/video.ogg#t=,02:00:00
>
> Specifies that the video should play from the beginning through two hours.
>
> http://foo.com/video.ogg#t=60,
>
> Specifies that the video should start playing at 60 seconds and play through the end of the video.